# How to separate a word in a list character by character in python?

Tags: python

```
import getpass
from art import *
tprint("Hangman")
def guess():
    guess_word = getpass.getpass("What's the word to guess? ")
    chracters = print("The chosen word has:\n",str(len(guess_word)),"charaters")
guess()
```

I have this piece of code for starting.
Does anyone know how to separate the variable "guess_word" in a list ["a", "z"] like that in python?
Thanks

Comment: `letters = list(guess_word)` if that's what you mean

Comment: please show expected input/result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a list of all characters in the word, i.e., `"word"` would become `["w", "o", "r", "d"]`:

```py
def guess():
    guess_word = getpass.getpass("What's the word to guess? ")
    print(f"The chosen word has:\n {len(guess_word)} charaters")

    characters = list(guess_word)
    return characters

characters = guess()
# Do something with the characters...
```

If you simply want to iterate the characters, you can treat the string like a list:

```py
guess_word = "guess me"

for char in guess_word:
    print(char)
# g
# u
# e
# s
# s
# 
# m
# e
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code may help!

```
   import getpass
from art import *
def guess():
    guess_word = getpass.getpass("What's the word to guess? ")
    print(f"The chosen word has:\n {len(guess_word)} charaters")

    characters = list(guess_word)
    return characters

characters = guess()
print(characters)


#INPUT:  guess_word
# output: ['g', 'u', 'e', 's', 's', '_', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd']
```